# foreach inside another with array

Tags: php, foreach

I have this php code foreach loop inside another foreach what I need is to set all the array value one by one on each loop(red, blue, green, black). I need to change **$green** in

```
data-percent="<?php foreach ($green as $row) { echo $row->ink_numbers; }?>">
```

with all the value in array one by one on each loop I try:

```
 data-percent="<?php foreach ('$'.echo $value as $row) { echo $row->ink_numbers; }?>">
```

but it does not work. PLEASE HELP

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
<?php
 $color  = array( 0 => 'red' , 1 => 'blue', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'black' );
 foreach ($color as $key => $value) {

?>


                                                                                    <!-- make $green dynamic -->
<div class="<?php echo $value; ?> progress-pie-chart" data-percent="<?php foreach ($green as $row) { echo $row->ink_numbers; }?>">
  <div class="ppc-progress">
    <div class="<?php echo $value; ?> ppc-progress-fill"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="<?php echo $value; ?> ppc-percents">
    <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
      <span>%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where is $green defined? Right now, $green is null, so you won't get anything doing foreach($green...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable name, like this:

```
<?php foreach ($$value as $row) { echo $row->ink_numbers; }?>"
```

So when `$value = 'green'` the foreach will loop through `$green`.

Comment: If he does that, $$value, when $value='green', is a string, not an array. So,  he will be performing foreach on a string and coming right back here. He still needs to define $green=array(...) somewhere.

Comment: @Kainaw I'm assuming that he has `$green` defined somewhere that he's just not showing us. A lot of new people do that, define a variable elsewhere in the code and not include it in their SO question.